# how to plot pie chart in python based on two features in my dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data set that count the default of credit card, the dataset have information about male and female and if they are default 0 or 1

I want to plot a pie chart of all default = 0  and how percent of male and how percent of female

also I want to print the percentage of the value of the total number of dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with

```
df.loc[df['default']==0,'gender'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail adding autopct='%1.1f%%'